# concatenating multiple fastq files

Tags: files, merge, bioinformatics

I have a folder with almost 100 files, organized in groups of 16 files each. I need to concatenate each of the 16 files of each group into a single file. For example, one group of file names is:

```
randomString_$groupName-
```

I have a folder with almost 100 samples, the sample are run on the Nextseq500 and are single stranded. Each sample is run on 4 Flowcells for the Nextseq500 having 4 lanes. So per sample 16 fastq files are generated (see example below). Now I want to concatenate all these files and generated one output with name `102697-001-001_R1.fastq.gz`

```
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz

HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz

HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz

HJJMYBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-GCCTCTAT_L001_R1.fastq.gz
HJJMYBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-GCCTCTAT_L002_R1.fastq.gz
HJJMYBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-GCCTCTAT_L003_R1.fastq.gz
HJJMYBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-GCCTCTAT_L004_R1.fastq.gz
```

All of the files above should be concatenated into a single file named `102697-001-001_R1.fastq.gz` (so keeping the string between the two first `_` and after the last `_` as the name).

I have tried:

```
$ cat HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz \
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz \
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz \
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz \
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz \
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz \
HGTLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz \
HGVLWBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L002_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L003_R1.fastq.gz \
HGWWHBGXX_102697-001-001_ATTACTCG-AGGCTATA_L004_R1.fastq.gz > 102697_001_001_R1.fastq.gz
```

and it works, but as I have a lot of files, I don't want to do manually.

Comment: Are these files compressed by regular `gzip`, or are they compressed by `bgzip` and indexed with `tabix`? (i.e. do you also have to regenerate any Tabix indexes?)

Comment: Yes they are just regular .gzip files.

Comment: You might want to ask this sort of question over on [bioinformatics.se] next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for name in ./*.fastq.gz; do
    rnum=${name##*_}
    rnum=${rnum%%.*}

    sample=${name#*_}
    sample=${sample%%_*}

    cat "$name" >>"${sample}_$rnum.fastq.gz"
done
```

This would iterate over all compressed Fastq files in the current directory and extract the sample name into the shell variable `sample`.  For all the filenames shown in the question, this would be `102697-001-001`.

The `rnum` variable will hold the `R#` bit at the end of the filename.

The sample name is extracted by taking the filename and first removing everything up to and including the first `_` character, and then removing everything after and including the first `_` character from that result.  The value for the `rnum` variable is extracted in a similar manner.

The file is then simply appended onto the end of the aggregated file using `cat >>`.
The output filename will be constructed from the sample name, the `R#`, and the string `.fastq.gz`.  For the shown files, this will be `102697-001-001_R1.fastq.gz`.

Gzip compressed files do not have to be uncompressed in order to concatenated them.  Uncompressing the resulting file will give you the uncompressed concatenation of all Fastq files.

---

Alternative way of doing this with `bash`, using a regular expression to figure out the output file name:

```
for name in ./*.fastq.gz; do
    if [[ "$name" =~ _([0-9-]+)_.*(..)\.fastq\.gz ]]; then
        outfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.fastq.gz"

        cat "$name" >>"$outfile"
    fi
done
```

The filename is matched against the regular expression

```
_([0-9-]+)_.*(..)\.fastq\.gz
```

The two groups (bits in parentheses) will pick out the relevant parts of the filename for us.  The first group captures a string that *only* consists of characters that are either digits or dashes. This group needs to be surrounded by `_` on either side.  The only place in the filename that this bit matches is the sample name.

After the first group, and the `_` after it, we allow for any number of any characters (`.*`) up to the `(..)\.fastq\.gz` bit. The `\.fastq\.gz` will match the `.fastq.gz` string at the end of the filename, so the last group, `(..)`, captures the `R1` immediately before that (the `.` pattern will match any one character, while `\.` will match a dot).

The two captured groups are stored as index 1 and 2 in the `BASH_REMATCH` array (the name is short for "Bash Regular Expression Match"), and we use these in constructing the output file name.

Comment: @H.K If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @kusalananda Can you kindly give the description of bash file.

Comment: @H.K The sting I added at the end? I will add an explanation.

Comment: @Kusalananda I tink there is some problem with thisfor name in ./*.fastq.gz; do
    rnum=${name##*_}
    rnum=${rnum%%.*}

    sample=${name#*_}
    sample=${sample%%_*}

    cat "$name" >"${sample}_$rnum.fastq.gz"
done   
I think there is some problem with this code, when i try amnually just the 1st sample the output file size is different from what this loop creates. The code that you posted before putting in rnum, it was working Ok. 
 The bash is working perfectly Ok

Comment: @H.K Yes, you have found a bug in my code.  The `cat >` should be `cat >>` as in the `bash` code.  I will update the answer at once. Thanks!

Comment: @H.K The difference is that `>` replaces the contents of the target file, while `>>` appends to the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something very similar for my work.

The solution that was the cleanest for me is as follows:

```
ls *.fastq.gz | cut -d '_' -f2 | sort | uniq | parallel -j 16 'cat *{}*.fastq.gz > {}_R1.fastq.gz'
```

In this code I:

1. find all files with the `.fastq.gz` extension. **Filenames are not allowed to contain special characters (eg., !?' '). See adminbee response to my comment.
2. `cut` the output of (1) by the delimiter `_` and save the second output (`-f2`)
3. `sort` the `cut` text
4. keep only the unique (i.e., `uniq`) text
5. send the unique text to `parallel`.
6. have `parallel` start up to 16 jobs (`-j 16`)
7. each parallel job runs the command

   ```
   'cat *{}*.fastq.gz > {}_R1.fastq.gz'
   ```

   This `cat` code should concatenate all files it finds matching the input (`{}`) from `uniq` in the directory in which the code is run. It will call the output file: `102697-001-001_R1.fastq.gz`.

I know that it doesn't automatically capture the `R1`. Perhaps someone could suggest a way to capture `R1` in my code?

What is great about this code is that it does this task for ***all*** unique samples in the directory. I had 32 files coming from 16 samples (i.e., `Sample1_L001.fastq` and `Sample1_L002.fastq`; `Sample2_L001` and `Sample2_L002`; etc...). This code concatenated them all by sample in one go. So I ended up with just `Sample1.fastq`, `Sample2.fastq`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that while your approach may work in your case, [parsing the output of `ls` is highly disrecommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) as it can fail when the filenames contain "special" characters, even as simple as a space.

Comment: Thank you for that information! :). I will add that caveat to my readme file and to the answer. Fortunately, I do not work with filenames that contain special characters. Nevertheless, it was very informative to read about the issues with parsing ls's output.